# Spring Cloud Hystrix - Semaphore timeout and response

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix

In the case of Spring Cloud apps that use Hystrix with the Semaphores strategy, the Semaphore does not interrupt execution. It detects the timeout after the execution finished, updates the statistics of the circuit breaker, but more important it sends a response error to the client. This is a problem since the request already executed successfully downstream, but the client will see an error.

Is it possible to send the actual response received from the downstream to the client and only update circuit breaker statistics?

Comment: @pvpkiran I don't think you really followed the question. Hystrix does wait for execution to finish in case of semaphores or interrupts the thread in case of threads strategy. With threads things are fine conceptually since the execution is interrupted and an error is sent to the client (of course sometimes it may be possible that the downstream execution is completed). With semaphores it is very common that the downstream execution finishes successfully, but the client sees an error.

Comment: We met the exactly same problem with semaphore strategy. We've tried to find the solution, but it seems that there is no solution for this problem. So we changed isolation strategy to threadpool because of this issue.